# Как узнать значение атрибута дочернего элемента?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть несколько вот таких блоков:

```
<div class="input-group">
   <input name="color">
</div>
<div class="input-group">
   <input name="model">
</div>
...
```

Нужно при клике на input-group определять значение атрибута **name** у дочернего `input`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.input-group').click(function(e){
  let $input = $(this).find('input[name]');
  console.log($input.val(), $input.attr('name'));
});
```

Comment: Вот, ещё бы воспроизводился бы здесь...))

Comment: @UModeL И пальцы за него загибать.

Comment: "Ладно. И так сойдёт" ))